# Compare two CSV files and output lines not found in first file into a third file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files which are file1.csv, and file2.csv. Both have multiple columns as follows:

a. file1.csv

```
username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
SreyTey1998,963229606,7854138709318981862,Smaradey Chan,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Srey_Tey_1,2079816779,6921382059939144796,Srey tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
sreytey123,5316691604,668712126044928206,Phat SreyTey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Sreytey168,5455045488,-714912998136226691,Vong Soksreytey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
SreyTey99,5653783510,-2575791274366210473,Oun Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
sreytey1919,5819100400,3174041461521242292,Tey Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Sreytey6666,6001252515,1586106578669001327,Srey Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
SreyTey7777,6026179841,5596849859821333867,Srey Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Ahh_Nak86,5637888996,-1267155033181296023,YÃ¬Ã¬ Ng,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
```

b. file2.csv

```
username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
SreyTey1998,963229606,7854138709318981862,Smaradey Chan,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Srey_Tey_1,2079816779,6921382059939144796,Srey tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
sreytey123,5316691604,668712126044928206,Phat SreyTey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
Sreytey168,5455045488,-714912998136226691,Vong Soksreytey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
SreyTey99,5653783510,-2575791274366210473,Oun Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
sreytey1919,5819100400,3174041461521242292,Tey Tey,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
AhhLyn1213,808888756,2482753619838480608,Ly-áž›áž¸ðŸŒˆâ¤ï¸,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahhly09,938983724,-8302570306911018211,æ–¹å¡”èŽ‰,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahh_vong,873218908,1743989214734522713,Mek Sreyvong,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahhnitaccd,5420585351,-6331445989210603589,NITA CCD,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
```

c. The output file as file2-nodups.csv, should be:

```
username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
AhhLyn1213,808888756,2482753619838480608,Ly-áž›áž¸ðŸŒˆâ¤ï¸,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahhly09,938983724,-8302570306911018211,æ–¹å¡”èŽ‰,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahh_vong,873218908,1743989214734522713,Mek Sreyvong,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
ahhnitaccd,5420585351,-6331445989210603589,NITA CCD,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
```

I have tried the following codes:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as t1:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
with open('file2.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as t2:
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

# scans through the two files and writes differences to new csv
with open('file2-nodups.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8") as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

The above does not work - because the output file (file2-nodups.csv) has the same content as file2.csv

Very appreciate any advice.

I would like to confirm that the above codes are Working for the following data:

```
    file1.csv:
    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
    asgie2,19933,29kd982hi4hh6h443,
    47uuha,491920,kdsagku5kkajgjag,
    james_sing,4002899,4asg37yragdh300asgdlk,
    joe_naro,4989222,hgjhe84jkaglagjj,
    48700245,hlvkiiwej8njnnrk320kc,

    file2.csv:
    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
    misschue,87340a,hgeikka83llagea,
    james_sing,4002899,4asg37yragdh300asgdlk,
    michell22,4883140,cn2ukkfhiigakgd3yhg,

    Output file:
    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
    misschue,87340a,hgeikka83llagea,
    michell22,4883140,cn2ukkfhiigakgd3yhg,
```

But they dont work for data with more columns above. Very appreciate any advice.

**UPDATE**: Python does not read strange characters correctly; that is why all suggested codes dont work. Those characters appear in the fourth column, for example,

ž‰ áž†áž¶áŸ†áž„áž£áž¸áž» ðŸ’—11 ""H1""",Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ

After replacing them with English or numbers or space characters, the codes work as expected.

The best solution to this is compare one column (second) which is unique to every line, and if its different, output those lines in file2.csv to the third file.

Here are my files:

```
    a. file1.csv

    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
    Manithbun,892557579,-8406919653747059917,Manith Bun.,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1128046905,-541590019988886083,M.r rithy phone shope â™¥ï¸â™¥ï¸â™¥ï¸,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    PET_KIMHEANG,1209296259,-3836506661281845754,áž–áŸáž áž‚áž¹áž˜áž áŸŠáž¶áž„áŸš,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1215736274,-3314364090375867636,"áž˜áŸ‰áž¶áž‰ áž†áž¶áŸ†áž„áž£áž¸áž» ðŸ’—11 ""H1""",Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1296059051,289341865810496004,áž€áž¼áž“ áž”áŸ‰áž¶áž”áŸ‰áž¶ áž€áŸ’ážšáž»áž˜áž¡áž¶áž“áž”áŸ‚áž“ážŸáŸ†áž”áž¼ážŸáŸ’áž“áŸáž áŸ,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    oun_Rorng,1330317717,-1815409784220647876,Mss Rorng,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1373051922,4933577293541799006,Soroth Phe,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    Veasnalove9999,1721055020,-7406583441966710751,Veasna Love,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461


    b. file2.csv

    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id
    Manithbun,892557579,-8406919653747059917,Manith Bun.,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1128046905,-541590019988886083,M.r rithy phone shope â™¥ï¸â™¥ï¸â™¥ï¸,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    PET_KIMHEANG,1209296259,-3836506661281845754,áž–áŸáž áž‚áž¹áž˜áž áŸŠáž¶áž„áŸš,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1215736274,-3314364090375867636,"áž˜áŸ‰áž¶áž‰ áž†áž¶áŸ†áž„áž£áž¸áž» ðŸ’—11 ""H1""",Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1296059051,289341865810496004,áž€áž¼áž“ áž”áŸ‰áž¶áž”áŸ‰áž¶ áž€áŸ’ážšáž»áž˜áž¡áž¶áž“áž”áŸ‚áž“ážŸáŸ†áž”áž¼ážŸáŸ’áž“áŸáž áŸ,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    oun_Rorng,1330317717,-1815409784220647876,Mss Rorng,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,1373051922,4933577293541799006,Soroth Phe,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    Veasnalove9999,1721055020,-7406583441966710751,Veasna Love,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    Thithseda,5185517950,-6420126539020087321,Thith Seda,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,5708325040,7960869157828131294,Tong Meang,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    takoma_05,396559485,4653963679316835279,V P,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461


    c. nodups.csv (the lines in file2.csv which are not found in file1.csv)

    Thithseda,5185517950,-6420126539020087321,Thith Seda,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    ,5708325040,7960869157828131294,Tong Meang,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
    takoma_05,396559485,4653963679316835279,V P,Zisy Ly áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž›áž»áž™0967699965,1806798461
```

I have tried the following codes, but nothing is written to the output file:

```
      import csv
      reader1 = csv.reader(open("file1.csv", 'r', encoding="utf8"))
      row1 = next(reader1)
      reader2 = csv.reader(open("file2.csv", 'r', encoding="utf8"))
      row2 = next (reader2)

      with open("nodups.csv", 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
           for row in reader2:
                if (row1[1] != row2[1]):
                     f.write(row)
```

Please advise how to make that work. Very appreciate any help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; `file2-nodups.csv` is generated with the expected two lines. Check if either file has subtle differences, like the maybe trailing spaces. Also, this is just naive line comparison, the fact that the files are in the CSV format is irrelevant as CSV is never parsed, or generated. Also also, strictly speaking, CSV does not allow extra spaces; the space next to comma will be taken as the content of the field, so you get values like `" 87340a"` instead of `"87340a"` that you presumably expect.

Comment: Dear Amadan, both files have the same titles like this: username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id

Comment: I run the codes again, the output file still has the same content as file2.csv. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Copy the data and code from your question and run it. You will see that "the output file still has the same content as file2.csv" is not true. Then figure out the difference between your actual data/code and the data/code you posted.

Comment: Hi Amanda, I did that. The output file still has got the same as file2.csv

Comment: I also updated the data without space as you advised. The result still the same. Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://www.online-python.com/uTJLnVUNpe) is your code and data, if you click the "Run" button, the output is `['misschue,87340a,hgeikka83llagea,\n', 'michell22,4883140,cn2ukkfhiigakgd3yhg,\n']`. The contents are _not_ the same as `file2.csv`.

Comment: so I need to add \n at the end of line? it seems working for previous data, but it does not work for my actual data which I have put in replacement of the previous one.

Comment: As a side note, only indent code blocks 4 spaces so that we can cut/paste the code without having to fiddle with it.

Comment: You mean it is not correct indentation?

Comment: As noted, your code works for the data presented. If your real data is having a problem, then pick one line that should not have been in the output file and compare character by character in python. Perhaps one file uses "\n" ending while the other uses "\r\n".

Comment: @Meng888 - Right. I edited your question so that the first two examples and the code can be copy/pasted without editing. If you try copy/paste on your final example, you'll notice you have 4 spaces at the beginning of each line that need to be removed.

Comment: Correct. I indented them for reading purposes. When they are in data for Python, they dont have indentation. Thanks

Comment: @tdelaney, I ll try to find out what the problem with actual data. However, I copied and pasted data in the same file into file1.csv, and file2.csv. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED: Compare two CSV files based on second column (user id) and print out the differences found in second file to third file:

```
    with open('file1.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as check_file:
        check_set = set([row.split(',')[1] for row in check_file])

    with open('file2.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as filetwo, open('file3.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line.split(',')[1] not in check_set:
                out_file.write(line)
```

Or use the followings with headers:

```
    with open('file1.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f1:
        fileone = set([row.split(',')[1] for row in f1]) # Retrieve data in 2nd column for all rows in first CSV file

    with open('file2.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as filetwo, open('nodups.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
        out_file.write('username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id' + '\n')
        for line in filetwo:   # Scan each line in second CSV file
            if line.split(',')[1] not in fileone: # If the data of that line is not found in first file, write it into third file
                out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that trailing whitespace or newline characters don't interfere with the comparison of your CSV files, you can modify your code to strip these characters from each line before comparing them. Here's an updated version of your code that includes this adjustment:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as t1:
     fileone = [line.strip() for line in t1.readlines()]

with open('file2.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as t2:
     filetwo = [line.strip() for line in t2.readlines()]
    
with open('file2-nodups.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outFile:
     for line in filetwo:
         if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line + '\n')
```

This code removes any leading or trailing whitespace from each line in both files before performing the comparison. When writing lines that are unique to the second file into the output file, it ensures that each line is properly formatted with a newline character at the end.

Comment: I have tried your codes above, they dont work for my updated actual data - the output file is the same as file2.csv. Very appreciate your help.

Comment: can you share complete files? some sample records in it

Comment: you got email address - I can send to it. Basically they are the same as I posted above except that they have many lines more like over 100k lines. The Headers or Titles are exactly the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSV files can have subtle differences that don't affect the actual values of a row but will cause them to miscompare. For instance, one may have escaped a value or used a different line ending sequence. You could use a CSV parser and get rid of errant spaces in cells to normalize the data before the compare. Since we don't have the failing data, this is just a guess at the problem.

```
import csv

def row_normalize(row):
    return [cell.strip() for cell in row]

with open('file1.csv', 'r', newline="", encoding="utf8") as t1:
    fileone = [row_normalize(row) for row in csv.reader(t1)]
    
with open('file2.csv', 'r', newline="", encoding="utf8") as t2:
    filetwo = [row_normalize(row) for row in csv.reader(t2)]

# scans through the two files and writes differences to new csv
with open('file2-nodups.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf8") as outFile:
    outCsv = csv.writer(outFile)
    for row in filetwo:
        if row not in fileone:
            outCsv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your codes above, the result is the same - the output file has the same content as file2.csv. I ll try to read a couple of lines in file1.csv and file2.csv to see why they are different?

Comment: That's a good idea. Copy the 2 files to temporary files so that you edit them without losing the real data. In each file, find a line that should match but doesn't. Delete all of the other lines. Run the code to make sure the line is copied to the output file. Then you'd have something simple to compare.

Comment: I found out that Python does not read these strange characters correctly: áž”áŸ„áŸ‡ážŠáž»áŸ†áž“áž¹áž„áž›áž€áŸ‹ážšáž¶áž™áž€áž˜áŸ’áž˜áž„áŸ‹áž–áž¸ážšáŸ„áž„áž…áž€áŸ’ážšáž•áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž›áŸ‹ðŸ“¥áž›áŸážážœáŸážšáž in the fourth column. The codes work as expected when they were removed and left with only English or number characters. I think the best way of solving this problem is compare only two columns (second and third) which are unique to every line. I posted this issue on another post, but it was said duplicated. I have post it again here at the bottom of my original post. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

using csv module you can read and write to the file

```
import csv

fields = ['username', 'user id', 'access hash', 'name', 'group', 'group id']  # headers of the nodups.csv file

formate_data = lambda rows_list: [row.replace('\n', '').strip() for row in rows_list]  # formatting any spaces
reader1 = [formate_data(row) for row in csv.reader(open("file1.csv", 'r', encoding="utf8"))]  # getting the data from the first file
reader2 = [formate_data(row) for row in csv.reader(open("file2.csv", 'r', encoding="utf8"))]  # getting the data from the second file

with open("nodups.csv", 'a', encoding="utf8", newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)  # writing headers
    for row in reader2:  # looping the file2.csv
        if row not in reader1:  # checking if row for file2.csv is not inside file1.csv
            writer.writerow(row)
```

this will make sure there are no spaces that will disturb the comparison process

```
formate_data = lambda rows_list: [row.replace('\n', '').strip() for row in rows_list]  # formatting any spaces
```

Comment: not working - generating the same result as three versions of codes above and with even two lines of headers.

Comment: how is it writing two lines of headers while the code clearly can only write one?
are you sure you're starting the correct Python script?
did you try to run it in a clean environment?

Comment: the first version has no headers because maybe I use split() to retrieve only data in second column without headers. That is why I need to add headers into output file before writing lines below them (second version). Thanks

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I have put some comments in my answers and hopefully they make sense to everyone. Thanks